# Promote featured products to top of category in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I wanted to have featured products promoted and listed first within category archive pages.

I found a lot of people with similar needs, and no ideal solutions, so I'm posting this here for others looking for this solution.

Answer (score 4):

The following code will add a "Recommended" option to the sorting options within the "Product Catalogue" section within the WooCommerce display settings (within the visual customizer). Set this new option as your default sorting option to have featured products promoted to the top, and listed first.

Add this code to your functions.php in your file (as always, use a child theme or code snippet plugin):

```
//add new sorting option
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['recommended'] = 'Recommended';
    return $sortby;
}

//set default sorting for new option
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );
function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
  $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    if ( 'recommended' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'date';
        $args['order'] = 'DESC';
        $args['meta_key'] = '';
    }
    return $args;
}

//adjust order to allow for featured posts
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'show_featured_products_orderby',10,2);
function show_featured_products_orderby($order_by, $query){
  global  $wpdb ;
  if( (!is_admin()) ){
    $orderby_value = ( isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( (string) $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) ) );
    $orderby_value_array = explode( '-', $orderby_value );
    $orderby = esc_attr( $orderby_value_array[0] );
    $order = ( !empty($orderby_value_array[1]) ? $orderby_value_array[1] : 'ASC' );
    $feture_product_id = wc_get_featured_product_ids();
    //only apply to recommended sorting option
    if ( $orderby == "recommended" && is_array( $feture_product_id ) && !empty($feture_product_id) ) {
      if ( empty($order_by) ) {
        $order_by = "FIELD(" . $wpdb->posts . ".ID,'" . implode( "','", $feture_product_id ) . "') DESC ";
      } else {
        $order_by = "FIELD(" . $wpdb->posts . ".ID,'" . implode( "','", $feture_product_id ) . "') DESC, " . $order_by;
      }
    }  
  }
  return $order_by;
}
```